# One print expression strangely depends on another print expression

Tags: python, jinja2

I have this Jinja2 template:

```
{% set input = 1 %}
{% set steps = [1, 2, 3, 4]|select("greaterthan", input) %}
{{ steps|list }}
{{ steps|first if steps|list|length > 0 else None }}
```

It prints:

```
[2, 3, 4]
None
```

Now I remove `{{ steps|list }}`.

```
{% set input = 1 %}
{% set steps = [1, 2, 3, 4]|select("greaterthan", input) %}
{{ steps|first if steps|list|length > 0 else None }}
```

It prints nothing at all.

Then instead of `{{ steps|list }}` I put `{{ steps|first }}`.

```
{% set input = 1 %}
{% set steps = [1, 2, 3, 4]|select("greaterthan", input) %}
{{ steps|first }}
{{ steps|first if steps|list|length > 0 else None }}
```

Now it prints:

```
2
```

What is wrong with `{{ steps|first if steps|list|length > 0 else None }}` that it behaves differently depending on what else I print?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Jinja, but this looks like `steps` is a generator of some sort (presumably due to the result of the `select` operation you apply to it).  Once you've consumed all of its elements via `steps|list`, there's nothing more you can get out of it.  Try putting `|list` at the end of the expression you assign to `steps`, so that it's a list from the start (that you can iterate over as many times as you want).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{% set steps = [1, 2, 3, 4]|select("greaterthan", input) %}` is like a generator expression, basically the same as Python code like this:

```py
steps = (select("greaterthan", item) for item in [1,2,3,4])
```

That is to say, `steps` is a generator from which you can only pull out the *next* value until the values are exhausted. So, when you do `{{ steps|list }}` at any point, you exhaust the generator and you can't iterate over the `steps` variable again.

So, the translation of what happens in your jinja code could be approximately illustrated as follows:

```py
>>> print(list(steps))  # exhausts the generator
[2, 3, 4]
>>> print(list(steps))  # no more values in the generator
[]
>>> print(len(list(steps))
0
```

What you probably wanted to do is first exhaust the generator into a list first and assign *that* value to the variable `steps`.

I would guess the jinja syntax for this would be to just add `|list`:

```
{% set steps = [1, 2, 3, 4]|select("greaterthan", input)|list %}
```

Comment: Oh, so the result of `|select()` can only be used once!